# Slow: Getting the results count of a query using a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

All I'd like to know is how many records there are in my query results but MySQL keeps kicking me off saying I have lost my connection. The query itself runs in about  a second.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT my208.eid AS contact, name AS the_status, cid208.lastmod AS status_date, boo208.boo_medium
FROM the_emails.my208
LEFT JOIN the_emails.cid208 ON cid208.eid = my208.eid
LEFT JOIN the_emails.boo208 ON boo208.eid = my208.eid
LEFT JOIN the_config.classes ON boo208.class_id = classes.id) foo
```

Why is this taking so long and is there a better way?

Comment: Why not include the `count(*)` in inner query itself.

Comment: In all likelihood, you have the wrong join conditions on the table.  Without more information, such as sample data, though, it is impossible to say.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're probably right it's my first day diving into a db in a new role and I'm exploring right now. I would have thought though, that if I can run the query foo itself in no time, then surely counting the results of that should be quick too?

Comment: Is there any reason why you use left joins? This will result in full table scans for the first three tables

Comment: @DougFirr . . . No.  When a human measures the response time of a query, a human usually measures the time to the first row returned.  When you do a `count(*)`, all the rows have to be generated for the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `count(*)` in your inner query itself. See the modified query below.

Give it a try

```
SELECT my208.eid AS contact, 
name AS the_status, 
cid208.lastmod AS status_date, 
boo208.boo_medium,
COUNT(*) as total_records
FROM the_emails.my208
LEFT JOIN the_emails.cid208 ON cid208.eid = my208.eid
LEFT JOIN the_emails.boo208 ON boo208.eid = my208.eid
LEFT JOIN the_config.classes ON boo208.class_id = classes.id
```

Comment: Oh I think I may have created confusion. the_emails is a database not a table

Comment: Isn't the_emails the database name?

Comment: Trying to run that query now but taking  along time too. But won't it give the count(*) of each record in the results, as opposed to the total number of records in my original query? Also, do I not have to add a group by clause when using an aggregate? I'm not that advanced on SQL so not sure but can't see the query results as of just now

Comment: @Doug: Without a group by you can't use aggegrate function in combination with other columns in the select. You'll get one row.

Comment: @Gervs what does "in combination with" mean in this situation? Just trying to understand. 
MySQL has just kicked me off too, keeps asking me for my password about 5 - 10 mins after starting to run the query, at which point the query cancels.

Comment: Sorry Doug, I addressed the wrong person (ment for Rahul). If have you aggegrate functions without a group by, the grouping is over the entire table

Comment: @Gervs, that's a wrong concept. You can use any aggregate function with/without `group by` clause. It's just that; if you use group by with a specific column then aggregate function works on that group else it works on entire table row. In this case, OP wants total row count returned and so there is no need of a `group by` (at least I don't see any).

Comment: @DougFirr, If it still taking long time, then check your index definition. You may want to post table schema along with result of explain plan of the above posted query.

Comment: @Rahul: The wrong concept is the way you use COUNT and other columns in de SELECT clause. Without a group by this will result in one row. MySQL will accept, but more strict db systems will throw an error.